# Is iOS 4.1 faster than iOS 4.0 on the iPhone 3G?

Tags: ios, iphone

There are numerous questions (and good answers!) about the fact that iOS 4.0 is horribly slow on an iPhone 3G.

**How about iOS 4.1?** Does anybody have any positive experiences to share? I'm staying on 3.1.3 for a long time still, or until any new v4.x isn't any slower.

Comment: iOS 4.1 is under NDA, so anyone who comments about it is breaking their contract with Apple.

Comment: OH! I didn't know, I thought it was already public. In that case, lets's just let this question linger here until people can safely provide answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rumours are that it is much faster: http://thenextweb.com/apple/2010/07/27/does-ios4-1-fix-slow-iphone3g-units-yes/

Comment: An excellent and very promising article! The video doesn't look like a parody to me at all, sadly. I've downgraded to 3.1.3 myself bcause of this. I'll wait with accepting the answer a bit, to see if anything else comes along too. Thanks!

Comment: Same my iPhone 3g is woefully slow with 4.0.1

Comment: I think the parody part of the video is the commentary and music/sound effects.